# Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware - Unprotect ticket failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, sitecore

I am using an ASP.NET MVC application to connect to AD using owin middleware. This is the startup class:

```
try 
{
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{});
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions 
                                           {
                                               Authority = Globals.Authority, 
                                               ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
                                               RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                                               PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                                               Scope = Globals.BasicSignInScopes,  // a basic set of permissions for user
                                                                                  // sign in & profile access
                                               TokenValidationParameters =
                                                   new TokenValidationParameters
                                                       {
                                                           // In a real application you would use ValidateIssuer = true for
                                                           // additional checks and security.
                                                           NameClaimType = "email", 
                                                           SaveSigninToken = false,
                                                           ValidateIssuer = false
                                                       },
                                               Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                                                   {
                                                       SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated,
                                                       AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                                                       AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                                                   },
                                               ResponseType = "id_token",
                                               ProtocolValidator = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator()
                                                   { 
                                                       RequireStateValidation = false,
                                                       RequireNonce = true},
                                                       CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
                                                   });
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    Log.Error("OwinMiddleWareIntialize Error", ex.Message);
}
```

We are using .NET Framework 4.8.

We are not getting redirected to the redirect URI which is mentioned in the AD, the screen is getting redirected to homepage.

I have checked some of the blogs they are asking to add the following code into `CookieAuthentication`

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
                                {
                                    // ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                                    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                                    CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
                                });
```

Any suggestion might help here thanks in advance

We are trying to authenticate AD login with Sitecore 10.2 docker using OwinMiddleware